# What can be said about continuity and differentiability of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sin^{2n} x+\cos^{2n} x)^{1\over 2n}$

What can be said about continuity and differentiability of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

$f(x)=1$ when $x=2k\pi$ and also multiple of $\pi/4$,$\pi/2$, when $x\in(0,1), f(x)=0$. So it is discontinuous for sure. but I am not able to find out the precise set of discontinuity and differentiability. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A start:** We can extend your calculations, and determine $f(x)$ for all $x$.

Suppose that $|\sin x|\le \cos x$.  Then
$$(\sin^{2n} x+\cos^{2n}x)^{1/(2n)}=|\cos x|(1+\tan^{2n}x)^{1/(2n)}.$$
Since $|\tan(x)|\le 1$ for these $x$, Squeezing shows that the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $|\cos x|$.

A similar argument shows that if $|\sin x|\gt |\cos x|$, then $f(x)=|\sin x|$.

These calculations should be enough to answer the questions about $f(x)$.

Comment: So, $f(x)=\max\{|\sin x|,|\cos x|\}$ :-o :-o ?

Comment: Yes, that is another way of putting it.